# appendChild doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The following snippet of code adds for javascript html to a page. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE not.

```
xmlHttp.onload = function() {
     if (xmlHttp.status === 200) {
        var okToComeBack = true;
        var responseJson = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        var environmentDiv = document.createElement('div');
        environmentDiv.setAttribute('class', 'container-environmentmarker');
        environmentDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="container-environment"><div class="environment-marker"></div></div>';
        document.body.appendChild(environmentDiv);        
        document.getElementsByClassName(that._config.environmentClass)[0].innerHTML = responseJson.nameOfEnvironment;
        document.getElementsByClassName(that._config.environmentMarkerClass)[0].setAttribute('class', that._config.environmentMarkerClass + ' ' + that._config.environmentMarkerClassPrefix + responseJson.colourOfMarker);

        if (responseJson.nameOfSite !== undefined) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(that._config.siteNameClass)[0].innerHTML = responseJson.nameOfSite;
        }
    }
};
```

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Also, FYI: set the `.innerHTML` on `environmentDiv` before you append it into the document so that you don't cause the entire DOM to be rebuilt and reflowed after you append it.

Comment: remove the line break from the String in `environmentDiv.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: IE 11, I think is the latest version.

Comment: @Thomas That is most likely just there because of the way the code was copied into the question. It would not cause the code before it to not run.

Comment: Well are there errors? Do you see anything in the console? How does it get triggered?

Comment: @ScottMarcus there's only one supported version of ie now, if microsoft don't offer support to older versions of ie anymore I don't see why we should

Comment: @Pete That's not relevant, nor was it the question.

Comment: @epascarello The console is clean, the div is just not appended.

Comment: The code works for me in IE 11.But, you do realize that none of the code you are appending has any content in it. If you add some text, you should see it working just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ah2f8j4r/

Comment: So how is it called? We need more info that what is provided. Did you ad console.log lines to see if it is called?

Comment: @ScottMarcus How is it not relevant?  You're asking what version of IE

Comment: @ScottMarcus don't think so. If it's just line-wrapping fron your text-editor the line break would not have been copied, nor would the line have been indented here. And maybe he confuses "not seeing" an empty div with the div having been appended. Although this should have thrown an Error.

Comment: @Pete Because regardless of the answer, the problem still exists and the OP still needs an answer. Just because the version is or isn't supported doesn't make the need for a solution to go away.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Fair enough, do you always ask what version of firefox and chrome they use too, just in case they are using old unsupported browsers?

Comment: @Pete No, I don't because those browsers don't have the history of non-standards support that IE does and those browsers weren't used by virtually all of the corporate world in the 90's and early 2000's to build proprietary solutions that still must be supported.

Comment: @Pete, besides ES6, 7, ... support do you know the differences in behaviour/quirks between the last 5 or so FF versions for example? Things you should be aware of? And do you think there are any significant differences as a web dev between IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 and Edge? To me, every IE version < 11 was almost like a completely different browser with its own quirks.

Comment: @Thomas I don't bother remembering the differences between different versions once they become unsupported by the company writing them, by continuing to support them you are pretty much saying to the people that still use them, yep you carry on and we'll spend the extra resources to support you, instead of making them upgrade so we can finally forget about all the bob browsers microsoft has thrown at us

Comment: @Pete I think you fundamentally miss the idea of what people use to browse in work vs. outside. There are still many millions of IE users inside the walls of the corporate world that work on proprietary systems built on some version of IE. When working with governments and municipalities, it is quite common to come across IE users because those environments generally have limited budgets, which make upgrading difficult.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i have added more code. :) Actually the div is filled with data dinamically.